# How to to show / hide divs based on one or more checkboxes checked

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a filter page for my website that will allow the user to check some checkboxes and then the corresponding products will appear. Currently figured out how to make filtering using event listeners but they only respond to one checkbox checked. How can I do this?

Also is there an option that all products are shown at the start of the page?

Here is the code I currently use:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".boardgame");
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

inputs.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('change', function() {

    if (this.checked) {
      elements.forEach(e => {
        if (e.getAttribute('data-all') == this.value) {
          e.style.display = "block";
        }
      })

    }
    if (this.checked) {
      elements.forEach(e => {
        if (e.getAttribute('data-categorie') == this.value) {
          e.style.display = "block";
        }
      })

    }
    if (this.checked) {
      elements.forEach(e => {
        if (e.getAttribute('data-minuten') == this.value) {
          e.style.display = "block";
        }
      })

    }
    if (this.checked) {
      elements.forEach(e => {
        if (e.getAttribute('data-spelers') == this.value) {
          e.style.display = "block";
        }
      })

    }
    if (this.checked) {
      elements.forEach(e => {
        if (e.getAttribute('data-leeftijd') == this.value) {
          e.style.display = "block";
        }
      })

    } else {
      elements.forEach(e => {
        if (e.getAttribute('data-categorie') || e.getAttribute('data-minuten') || e.getAttribute('data-spelers') || e.getAttribute('data-leeftijd') == this.value) {
          e.style.display = "none";
        }
      })
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.boardgame {
  display: none;
}

img {
  height: 265px;
  width: 265px;
}
```

```html
<div class="filterlist">
  <h4>Alle spellen</h4>
  <label class="container-filter">Alles
                <input type="checkbox" value="all" id="all" checked>
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
              </label>
  <h4>Speelminuten</h4>
  <label class="container-filter">15 - 30 min.
                <input type="checkbox" value="15">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
              </label>
  <label class="container-filter">30 - 60 min.
                <input type="checkbox" value="30">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
              </label>
  <label class="container-filter">60 - 90 min.
                <input type="checkbox" value="60">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
              </label>
  <label class="container-filter">90 - 120 min.
                <input type="checkbox" value="90">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
              </label>
  <label class="container-filter">Meer dan 120 min.
                  <input type="checkbox" value="120">
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
  <h4>Aantal spelers</h4>
  <label class="container-filter">1 of meer spelers
                <input type="checkbox" value="1">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
              </label>
  <label class="container-filter">Vanaf 2 spelers
                <input type="checkbox" value="2">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
              </label>
  <label class="container-filter">Vanaf 3 spelers
                <input type="checkbox" value="3">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
              </label>
  <label class="container-filter">Vanaf 4 spelers
                  <input type="checkbox" value="4">
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
  <h4>Categorieën</h4>
  <label class="container-filter">Familie
                    <input type="checkbox" value="familie">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
  <label class="container-filter">Strategie
                    <input type="checkbox" value="strategie">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
  <label class="container-filter">Fantasy
                        <input type="checkbox" value="fantasy">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
  <label class="container-filter">Coöperatief
                    <input type="checkbox" value="coop">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
  <label class="container-filter">Deductief
                        <input type="checkbox" value="deductief">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
  <label class="container-filter">Kinder
                        <input type="checkbox" value="kind">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
  <label class="container-filter">Kaart
                        <input type="checkbox" value="kaart">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
  <h4>Leeftijd vanaf</h4>
  <label class="container-filter">8 jaar
                    <input type="checkbox" value="8">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
  <label class="container-filter">10 jaar
                    <input type="checkbox" value="10">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
  <label class="container-filter">12 jaar
                        <input type="checkbox" value="12">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
  <label class="container-filter">15 jaar
                    <input type="checkbox" value="15">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
  <label class="container-filter">18 jaar
                        <input type="checkbox" value="18">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
</div>

<ul class="products" id="products">
  <div class="boardgame" data-minuten="90 - 120" data-spelers="3" data-leeftijd="12" data-all="all" data-categorie="Strategie">
    <li>
      <img src="img/Catan-Inkas-1.jpg" alt="Catan Histories: Rise of the Inkas">
      <h3>Catan Histories: Rise of the Inkas</h3>
      <button class="productbutton" onclick="window.location.href = 'catan-rise-of-the-incas.html'">Bekijk assortiment</button>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="boardgame" data-minuten="30 - 60" data-spelers="2" data-leeftijd="8" data-all="all" data-categorie="Family">
    <li>
      <img src="img/Carcassonne.jpg" alt="Carcassonne">
      <h3>Carcassonne</h3>
      <button class="productbutton" onclick="window.location.href = 'carcassonne.html'">Bekijk assortiment</button>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="boardgame" data-minuten="30 - 60" data-spelers="2" data-leeftijd="12" data-all="all" data-categorie="Coop">
    <li>
      <img src="img/Paranormal-Detectives.jpg" alt="Paranormal Detectives">
      <h3>Paranormal Detectives</h3>
      <button class="productbutton" onclick="window.location.href = 'paranormaldetectives.html'">Bekijk assortiment</button>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="boardgame" data-minuten="90 - 120" data-spelers="3" data-leeftijd="12" data-all="all" data-categorie="Strategie">
    <li>
      <img src="img/catan-cities-and-knights.jpg" alt="Catan: Cities & Knights Expansion">
      <h3>Catan: Cities & Knights Expansion</h3>
      <button class="productbutton" onclick="window.location.href = 'catan-cities-and-knights.html'">Bekijk assortiment</button>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="boardgame" data-minuten="60 - 90" data-spelers="2" data-leeftijd="12" data-all="all" data-categorie="Coop">
    <li>
      <img src="img/Thanos-Rising.jpg" alt="Thanos Rising – Avengers: Infinity War">
      <h3>Thanos Rising – Avengers: Infinity War</h3>
      <button class="productbutton" onclick="window.location.href = 'thanos-rising.html'">Bekijk assortiment</button>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="boardgame" data-minuten="90 - 120" data-spelers="2" data-leeftijd="12" data-all="all" data-categorie="Strategie">
    <li>
      <img src="img/Marco-Polo-II.jpg" alt="Marco Polo II: In the Service of the Khan">
      <h3>Marco Polo II: In the Service of the Khan</h3>
      <button class="productbutton" onclick="window.location.href = 'marco-polo-2-in-the-service-of-the-khan.html'">Bekijk assortiment</button>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="boardgame" data-minuten="90 - 120" data-spelers="2" data-leeftijd="15" data-all="all" data-categorie="Fantasy">
    <li>
      <img src="img/dune.jpg" alt="Dune">
      <h3>Dune</h3>
      <button class="productbutton" onclick="window.location.href = 'dune.html'">Bekijk assortiment</button>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="boardgame" data-minuten="60 - 90" data-spelers="1" data-leeftijd="15" data-all="all" data-categorie="Deductief">
    <li>
      <img src="img/Chronicles.jpg" alt="Chronicles of Crime">
      <h3>Chronicles of Crime</h3>
      <button class="productbutton" onclick="window.location.href = 'chronicles-of-crime.html'">Bekijk assortiment</button>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="boardgame" data-minuten="30 - 60" data-spelers="2" data-leeftijd="8" data-all="all" data-categorie="Family">
    <li>
      <img src="img/Kingdom-Builder-Family-Box.jpg" alt="Kingdom Builder Family Box">
      <h3>Kingdom Builder Family Box</h3>
      <button class="productbutton" onclick="window.location.href = 'kingdom-builder-family-box.html'">Bekijk assortiment</button>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="boardgame" data-minuten="15 - 30" data-spelers="3" data-leeftijd="8" data-all="all" data-categorie="Family">
    <li>
      <img src="img/just-one.jpg" alt="Just One">
      <h3>Just One</h3>
      <button class="productbutton" onclick="window.location.href = 'just-one.html'">Bekijk assortiment</button>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a common `name` for all checkboxes and query all checked checkboxes. You will be able to get array of values. Based on the value you can show or hide the checkboxes.  If array is empty, show all checkboxes. You can use `change` event listener to detect the checkbox change

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will look into it!

Answer (score 0):

A list of details needs to be improved in your code:

- **In first place** you should avoid the use of onclick functions to make a redirection when you can simply wrap these product buttons in `<a>` tags.
- **In second place** the reason because all the elements are not showing at the start of the page is because the class `.boardgame` that is giving all the games the property `display: none`.
- **In third place** you should check your function because is not right for what you are trying to accomplish, you should for example create an array of properties and then show or hide games based on the elements of that array, so when you click on a checkbox the corresponding value of the array changes and then refresh the games that are showing in order to fit with the properties of the array.

I hope that this helps you to get in the way and if you have a specific question while working on this I can give you a hand!

Comment: Great suggestions and will implement them, if I have more questions I will let you know! Thanks.